# Input not taken from eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying simple "printing your name C program in Eclipse CDT", but the console is not reading the user input.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
      char* name = NULL;
      printf("enter you name ");

      gets(name);

      printf("Hi");
      fflush(stdout);
      puts(name);

      return 0;
    }
```

This is the output I get:

```
    enter you name Hi
```

Any idea why this is not reading the input from the user?

Answer (score 2):

`gets` doesn't allocate memory for you, so your example causes undefined behavior. Also, its use is highly discouraged because of the ease of causing buffer overflows.
Use

```
char name[SIZE];
fgets(name, SIZE, stdin);
```

instead. From `man gets`:

> Never use `gets()`.

Shouldn't get any clearer.